# Formatting stdout in a debug task of Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Assuming the below tasks:

```yaml
- shell: "some_script.sh"
  register: "some_script_result"

- debug:
    msg: "Output: {{ some_script_result.stdout_lines }}
```

I receive the below output:

```json
"msg": "Output: [u'some_value',u'some_value2,u'some_value3]"
```

How do I get the output to print as?

```yaml
"msg":
Output:
  - some_value
  - some_value2
  - some_value3
```

Ansible version is 2.4.2.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try [this](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/use-ansibles-yaml-callback-plugin-better-cli-experience) option. You’ll love it.

There's a new YAML callback plugin introduced with Ansible 2.5 — meaning any machine running Ansible 2.5.0 or later can automatically start using this format without installing custom plugins.

To use it, edit your *ansible.cfg* file (either globally, in */etc/ansible/ansible.cfg*, or locally in your playbook/project), and add the following lines under the `[defaults]` section:

```ini
# Use the YAML callback plugin.
stdout_callback = yaml
# Use the stdout_callback when running ad-hoc commands.
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
```

Now I can easily read through your output message

If you get the following error:

> ERROR! Invalid callback for stdout specified: yaml

run

```bash
ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
```

Comment: Thank you. Since I'm presently stuck on 2.4.2 are there any filters to achieve a similar capability?

Comment: Ansible 2.4+ has built-in support for human-readable results:

Temporarily by setting ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug in the environment

`export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug`

or permanently by setting stdout_callback=debug in the [default] section of ansible.cfg

[default]
# human-readable stdout/stderr results display
stdout_callback = debug

From [Github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27078)

Comment: I couldn't see `ansible.cfg` file in`/etc/ansible` location. But there is a different file named `ansible.cfg.rpmsave`. Editing this file also fix the issue. Just for anyone confused about not having `ansible.cfg` file.

Comment: I generally have a copy of `ansible.cfg` in the same directory as where I'm executing ansible or ansible-playbook. I know someone somewhere says that isn't a good idea, but I do it anyways.

Comment: Having an `ansible.cfg` is a perfect option to me. Do you know why couldn't it be a good idea? :D

Answer (score 9):

What I found to work best so far for getting CLI-like output in Ansible, and which should work out of the box (at least for me on Fedora 34, Ansible 2.9), is setting the [`unixy` callback for condensed Ansible output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/unixy_callback.html)

```ini
stdout_callback = unixy
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
```

in your `ansible.cfg`. Given the tasks

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: uptime
      shell: uptime
    - name: volumes
      shell: "df -h"
```

the output in the terminal will look like

```bash
- all on hosts: all -
uptime...
  host1 done | stdout:  08:20:09 up 33 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.55, 0.27, 0.26
  host2 done | stdout:  08:20:09 up 1 day,  1:39,  1 user,  load average: 0.18, 0.17, 0.17

volumes...
  host1 done | stdout: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.2G  1.5G  5.4G  21% /overlay/pivot
devtmpfs        212M     0  212M   0% /dev
none            217M     0  217M   0% /overlay/pivot/overlay
none            217M  137M   80M  64% /overlay/rwdata
overlay         217M  137M   80M  64% /
tmpfs           217M     0  217M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           217M   25M  192M  12% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           217M     0  217M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   53M  200M  21% /boot
tmpfs            44M     0   44M   0% /run/user/1000
  host2 done | stdout: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.2G  1.5G  5.4G  22% /overlay/pivot
devtmpfs        212M     0  212M   0% /dev
none            217M     0  217M   0% /overlay/pivot/overlay
none            217M  103M  114M  48% /overlay/rwdata
overlay         217M  103M  114M  48% /
tmpfs           217M     0  217M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           217M  5.8M  211M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           217M     0  217M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   53M  200M  21% /boot
tmpfs            44M     0   44M   0% /run/user/1000


- Play recap -
  host1           : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
  host2           : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You should be able to list all available callback plugins using `ansible-doc -t callback -l` and their respective documentation using `ansible-doc -t callback <plugin name>`

**Source Documentation**

- [Callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html)
- [Index of all Callback Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Another Option**

Another option of [Improving the Ansible output](https://www.axians.co.uk/news/improving-the-ansible-output-with-anstomlog/) is downloading the [`callbacks\anstomlog.py`](https://github.com/octplane/ansible_stdout_compact_logger/blob/main/callbacks/anstomlog.py) from [Ansible STDOUT Compact Logger](https://github.com/octplane/ansible_stdout_compact_logger), store it under

```bash
tree ansible     
ansible
├── ansible.cfg
├── callbacks
│   ├── anstomlog.py
└── playbooks
    └── nginx.yaml
```

and configure inside `ansible/ansible.cfg`.

```
ANSIBLE_CONFIG=ansible/ansible.cfg ansible-playbook -u centos --private-key .ssh/key -i `terraform output bastion_ip`, ansible/playbooks/nginx.yaml
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The possible answers is using an other [Callback Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html)

```ini
[defaults]
nocows = True
# minimal, debug, yaml
stdout_callback = yaml
```

or

```bash
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug ansible-playbook ....
```

**Reference / Bug Report**

- [Ansible Issue #27078 - "*Why is Ansible's default output not more human readable... stilll?*"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27078)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying do the following changes, still i did not got the output format of yaml or debug options output properly. Later i found the ansible user configuration pick up it from user's config file. So i changed callbacks at user specific location and it worked.

```
[automation@ansibleserver ~]$ ansible --version
   ansible 2.9.9
   config file = /home/automation/ansible.cfg


# Use the YAML callback plugin.
   stdout_callback = yaml
# Use the stdout_callback when running ad-hoc commands.
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
```

So ensure, even though you changed at /etc/ansible/ansible.conf , try at user's config file too to get the good result.  instead of yaml , debug also gives good helpful format ( for linux users)