# Ansible: Grep and register output

Tags: ansible

I have just written an Ansible task to run an update script:

```
- name: Run Tdarr Updater
  command: grep -r /opt/tdarr/Tdarr_Updater | grep [INFO]
  register: updater_result

- name: Show Output 
  debug: msg="{{ updater_result.stdout_lines }}"
```

It works just fine, but I am unhappy with the output, check this screenshot:

[image]

I need only the lines with `[INFO]`, the others ones are not interessting...

When I run `/opt/tdarr/Tdarr_Updater | grep [INFO]`, I receive the output that I wanted:

```
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.614] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater - Tdarr_Updater | v2.00.12
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.615] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater - Tdarr_Updater | Required platform_arch:linux_x64
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.616] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater -
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.616] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater -
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.617] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater - Tdarr_Node | Current version: 2.00.12 | Required version: 2.00.12
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.617] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater - Tdarr_Node | Up to date! Version: 2.00.12!
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.618] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater -
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.619] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater -
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.619] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater - Tdarr_Server | Current version: 2.00.12 | Required version: 2.00.12
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.619] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater - Tdarr_Server | Up to date! Version: 2.00.12!
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.620] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater -
[2022-01-01T22:31:31.620] [INFO] Tdarr_Updater - Finished!
```

How can I save the `grep` output into the register?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in the must read help article [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because of the pipe `|` in your command you may have a look into [whats the difference between ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804071/)

> *It can be used if you want to execute more complex commands, for example commands concatenated with pipes*

and use

```yaml
- name: Run Tdarr Updater
  shell:
    cmd: grep -r /opt/tdarr/Tdarr_Updater | grep [INFO]
  changed_when: false
  register: updater_result
```

**Further readings**

- [Ansible `stdout` formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009505/)
- [Callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html)

Comment: Thank You for the link!

`- name: Run Tdarr Updater
  shell: /opt/tdarr/Tdarr_Updater | grep [INFO]
  register: updater_result`

did the trick :)