# Neatly print Ansible debug output on multiple lines

Tags: ansible

I have a file that I want to print as debug msg line.

```bash
cat  result.txt
## BEGIN :##  Role Name: Deployment Checks
## REASON:- ERROR: Deployment Checks output from command FATAL: TEST FAILED.
## END :##  Role Name: Deployment Checks ##

## BEGIN :##  Role Name: Describe the instance
## REASON:- ERROR: Describe the instance   FATAL: TEST FAILED.
## END :##  Role Name: Describe the instance ##
```

I m using the below code to print them on the console

```yaml
- name: Read result
  shell: "cat  result.txt | grep 'REASON:-'"
  register: result

- name: print checks fail.
  debug:
    msg:
      - "Check Failed!"
      -  "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Which prints below output in an ugly format as single line

```
TASK [ print checks fail.] **************************************************
fatal: [10.203.116.90]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": ["Check Failed!", ["REASON:- ERROR: Deployment Checks output from command", "REASON:- ERROR: Describe the instance  "]]}
```

How can I print every reason as a single line? So that output is more readable. Something like below

```
TASK [ print checks fail.] **************************************************
    fatal: [10.203.116.90]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
["Check Failed!", 
["REASON:- ERROR: Deployment Checks output from command",
"REASON:- ERROR: Describe the instance  "]]}
```

Answer (score 5):

Without a change of callback, you could do:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ['Check Failed!'] + result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Which will render in

```json
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Check Failed!",
        "## REASON:- ERROR: Deployment Checks output from command FATAL: TEST FAILED.",
        "## REASON:- ERROR: Describe the instance   FATAL: TEST FAILED."
    ]
}
```

But as pointed by [@U880D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72478720/2123530), the YAML callback is way more convenient to format output properly.

For example, with the YAML output, you could do:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |-
      Check Failed!
      {{ result.stdout }}
```

Which will render in

```json
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    Check Failed!
    ## REASON:- ERROR: Deployment Checks output from command FATAL: TEST FAILED.
    ## REASON:- ERROR: Describe the instance   FATAL: TEST FAILED.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look into [Callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) and configure it in `ansible.cfg` in example with `stdout_callback: yaml`.

By using this

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Read result
    shell:
      cmd: "grep 'REASON:-' result.txt"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

the result would be

```
TASK [Show result] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - '## REASON:- ERROR: Deployment Checks output from command FATAL: TEST FAILED.'
  - '## REASON:- ERROR: Describe the instance   FATAL: TEST FAILED.'
```

as required.

According your example it seems that you have currently configured `stdout_callback: json`, and according [Ansible Issue #76556](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/76556) it can't be specified in the playbook level.

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible `stdout` formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50017860/6771046)

**Ansible Documentation**

- [Index of all Callback Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html)