# Access to YAML file based nested variables in Ansible

Tags: variables, ansible, syntax, nested

Imagine I have a YAML configuration file config.yml like the following:

```yaml
---
vendor:
  url: https://acme.com
```

According to Ansible documentation, I can load this data structure into a variable:

```yaml
- name: Include vars of stuff.yaml into the 'stuff' variable (2.2).
  ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    file: {{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'STUFF') }}
    name: stuff
```

But how to use this variable and its subsidiaries? How to access the `stuff/vendor/url` variable properly, and is there a way to print out the whole variable tree?

Answer (score 0):

To use those variables, you have to use the [templating system of Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html), which is [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/).

Since your variable is currently an URL, here would be an example usage:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: "{{ stuff.vendor.url }}"
    dest: /tmp/vendor_page_copy
```

---

To see the content of the variable, you can:

1. use the `debug` module with the `var` parameter:

   ```yaml
   - ansible.builtin.debug:
       var: stuff.vendor.url
   ```

   which outputs something like

   ```yaml
   ok: [localhost] => 
     stuff.vendor.url: https://acme.com
   ```

   or

   ```yaml
   - ansible.builtin.debug:
       var: stuff
   ```

   which outputs something like

   ```yaml
   ok: [localhost] => 
     stuff:
       vendor:
         url: https://acme.com
   ```
2. use the `debug` module with the `msg` parameter, and template the variable:

   ```yaml
   - ansible.builtin.debug:
       msg: "{{ stuff.vendor.url }}"
   ```

   which outputs something like

   ```yaml
   ok: [localhost] => 
     msg: https://acme.com
   ```

   The same can be done with `msg: "{{ stuff }}"`, as seen above.
3. run your playbook with the `-v` option:

   ```bash
   ansible-playbook play.yml -v
   ```

   which outputs something like

   ```yaml
   ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
     ansible_facts:
       stuff:
         vendor:
           url: https://acme.com
     ansible_included_var_files:
     - /usr/local/ansible/stuff.yml
   ```

*<sup>Note: your own output would seem really different that was is displayed here, and be in JSON, in a hard to read one liner. If this is the case, you would greatly benefit from using the [YAML callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50009505/2123530).</sup>*